# Securing Application Pages in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating some application pages that can only be viewed by one AD group and everyone else should be denied access.  Can I use roles authorization like I would in an ASP.NET WebForms application by dropping in a web.config for the specific application?  If not, what would be the best way to handle security?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, doing role based stuff in web.config will work and I have done such a thing.

Comment: Watch out for multiple server issues with manual web.config edits. SharePoint generally handles adding and dropping web servers automatically.

Comment: Agree with Tom on this, use SPWebConfigModification to deploy web.config changes using a feature

Comment: Mark i am also trying to such project on my own, can you provide me directions on how to achive such funcationality.